# req.body is NULL {} on POST request

Tags: javascript, json, express, body-parser

[image: The code]

On post request from POSTMAN req.body is sending the data but returns { } when submitting the form.

This is what I used as the middleware,

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
```

but the word bodyParser is marked with the message 'bodyparser is deprecated'.ts(6385),
The declaration was marked as deprecated here.

I tried using,

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
```

but still its returning { }  on req.body

[image: body-parser image along with the flashed message]

Answer (score 1):

See the coding line when you are registering dependencies, if you register express json, that should be before your route, so it's look like :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// middleware registered here
app.use(express.json());

// then your route
app.post('/someroute', async (req,res,next) => {
  const { param1, param2 } = req.body;
  try {
    console.log(`${param1} and ${param2} written in terminal);
    res.send('ok');
  } catch (err) {
    res.send('oopps');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using correct headers when you're sending your POST request?

For `.json()` parsing, your headers should contain: `Content-Type: application/json`

For `urlencoded()` form data parsing, your headers should contain: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Can you also share the CURL of your Postman request?

Comment: Yes, header contains the Content-Type as: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, in the body i am sending the keys and value and getting the result in the console. But as soon as i am filling up the form and submitting it's returning '{ }' with object ID being saved in the database,